# SQL Join for child records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggle with a SQL join for parent client records (literally in my example!). My db tables are made up of something like (excuse the very generic example).

```
Table Room
Room No
  1
  2
  3

Table Customer
| Customer ID | Customer Name       | Associated
|   1        |    Joe Bloggs        |  
|   2        |    Little Bloggs     | 1
|   3        |    Little bloggs pet | 2

Table Bookings
| Room No | Customer |
| 1       |    1     |
```

What I'm after, is some SQL to grab the full 3 levels and room e.g.

```
Room   Customer
1      Joe Bloggs
1      Little Bloggs
1      Little Bloggs pet
```

There isnt a direct join on customer 2 and 3, but they are inherited via customer 1 to room 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a recursive [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Something like below

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  CustomerID,
                CustomerName,
                b.Room
        FROM    Customer c INNER JOIN
                Bookings b  ON  c.CustomerID = b.Customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  c.CustomerID,
                c.CustomerName,
                v.Room
        FROM    Vals v INNER JOIN
                Customer c  ON  c.Associated = v.CustomerID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with Cte (RoomId,Name ,CustomerId)
as(
   Select R.RoomId,C.Name,C.CustomerId
    From Booking B
     Inner Join Customer C on C.CustomerId=B.Customer
     Inner Join Room R On R.RoomId=B.RoomNo
    Union All
    Select Cte.RoomId,Cus.Name,Cus.CustomerId
    From Customer Cus
        inner join Cte On Cte.CustomerId=Cus.Associated
)

Select RoomId,Name  from Cte
```

Read more [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using CTE, please check the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83e64/12) for the sample

Have provided the CTE part below, please note, have renamed *Associated* to *AssociatedCustomerID* to make it more meaningful:

```
    WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, 0 [Level]
    FROM    Customer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CTE.CustomerID, CTE.CustomerName, Customer.AssociatedCustomerID, Level + 1
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN Customer
                ON CTE.AssociatedCustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
    WHERE   Customer.AssociatedCustomerID IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT  c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, c.AssociatedCustomerID AssociatedCustomerID , Bookings.RoomID
FROM    (   SELECT  *, MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName) [MaxLevel]
            FROM    CTE
        ) c
INNER JOIN Bookings on ISNULL(c.AssociatedCustomerID,c.CustomerID) = Bookings.CustomerID
WHERE   MaxLevel = Level
```