# SQL join on multiple levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm struggle with a SQL join for parent client records and just posted a query, but I realised after posting it that my example was slightly wrong (but still a useful post) so i've created a new one, that's more accurate :)

If i have the following database structure:

```
Table Regions
|Region_no | Region_Level  | owning_region_no |
| 1        |     1         |                  |
| 2        |     2         |          1       |
| 3        |     2         |          1       |
| 4        |     3         |          2       |
| 5        |     3         |          2       |
| 6        |     3         |          3       |

Table Postcodes
| Postcode | Region_no |
| PO32 3AE |     4     |
| PO32 3AA |     5     |
| PO32 3AF |     6     |

Table UnitsMappings
| Unit_No | region_no |
| 1       |     1     |
| 1       |     2     |
| 2       |     2     |
| 2       |     1     |
| 3       |     3     |
| 3       |     3     |
| 4       |     6     |
| 4       |     5     |

Table Units
| Unit_no | Unit_Name  |
|   1     |  South     |
|   2     |  SouthEast |
|   3     |  Central |
|   4     |  SouthWest |
```

[Updated sample answer] 
What I really want, is the following:

```
| Unit_name | Postcode |
| South     | PO32 3AE |
| South     | PO32 3AA |
| South     | PO32 3AF |
| SouthEast | PO32 3AE |
| SouthEast | PO32 3AA |
| SouthEast | PO32 3AF |
```

Even though South has only regions 1 and 2 mapped to it, the level 3's are mapped to the level 2's and then 1's (and the postcodes are mapped to the level 3's)

Now the difficulty is, that i just want the postcodes (from the postcode tables) which are associated to the level 3 regions levels in regions. So there may be a region level 1 associated to a unit_no, but i need all of the postcodes at the bottom that are mapped to the level 3.

Comment: Plus, how do you nicely format the above in markup!? Thanks @Szymon

Comment: Four spaces make it a code. There's a button in the editor that looks like `{}` to do it easy.

Comment: @midland-monkey: You need to use [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)...Answered something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857346/sql-join-for-child-records/22857554#22857554)

Answer (score 0):

based on your details here's my mapping ,

unit => units_mapping

units_mapping => (Postcodes or regions) // assuming using all table we use postcodes

Postcodes => regions

regions (main)

```
select reg.region_no, Units.name , pc.postcodes
from regions reg,
     Postcodes pc,
     UnitsMappings UM,
     Units units
where reg.region_no = pc.region_no and 
      pc.region_no = UM.region_no and
      UM.Unit_No = Units.Unit_no
order by reg.region_no asc
```

if there is null in one table, the record won't appear ... 
to handle use inner join

not yet tested ..... just assume :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid unit name in you test data for the region in region level 3.

The region with region level 3 are 4, 5 and 6.
There is no unit associated with region 4, the unit associated with region 5 and 6 is the unit 4, but in the table unit_name there is no unit 4.

If you have the data then this query will get the data

```
SELECT pc.postcode, u.unit_name
FROM regions reg
     INNER JOIN Postcodes pc ON reg.region_no = pc.region_no
     INNER JOIN UnitsMappings um ON reg.region_no = um.region_no
     INNER JOIN Units u ON um.unit_no = u.unit_no
WHERE reg.region_level = 3
```

changing the join on Units from INNER to LEFT will get you the postcodes with NULL as unit_name with the test data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
Select u.Unit_name,pc.Postcode from Units as u
inner join UnitsMappings um on u.Unit_no = um.Unit_no
inner join Postcodes as pc on pc.Region_no = um.region_no
```

Comment: I've just tried this @AK47 but I'm getting quite a few null postcodes which i shouldn't get.

Comment: Ahh yes, I may well do. Due to the left join, its getting everything from one particular table which may have more in there than needed. I'll just add in a where cause :)

Comment: @midland-monkey, changed, now check. Please always try to mention your specification properly in question.

Comment: Ah @AK47, no this isn't working as this is what I'd already done :) It just matches with the level 3's. If the level 1 is mapped, i need to dig down to get all of the postcodes mapped to the level 3's also which is the headache..

Comment: Please post a sample ans.

Comment: how your UnitsMappings table has a link to Region no 6, can you explain relation please.

Comment: Thats the master linking table, where you can specify the units and regions. You can set the regions and level 1,2 or 3. If you select level 1, you inherit the level 2 and 3's. The postcodes are mapped to the level 3's so you get all of of those postcodes which is what i'm trying to pull out

Comment: I am trying Recursive CTE too, but to be frank, I am not able to understand relationships of tables.